# getAttribute in javascript showing null value

Tags: javascript

```
var rs_body=document.getElementById('temp_rs');
var rows=rs_body.getElementByTagName("tr");
for(i=0; i < rows.length; i++)
{
    var cells=rows[i].getElementByTagName("td");
    for(j=0; j<cells.length; j++)
    {
        var cell=cells[j].getAttribute("border_cell myFont");
    }       
    var row=rows[i].getAttribute('pid')
}
```

above is my code here i want value of cell in var by above code it showing null

tmp_rs Table

```
<tbody id="temp_rs">
     <tr id="r_1" class="list" pid="1" >
         <td class="border_cell myFont" align="center" > 1 </td>
         <td class="border_cell myFont" align="center" > abc </td>
     </tr >
</tbody>
```

i want to get `td` value `1,abc` in var cell and can't make change in table.

Comment: The attribute is **`class`**. `border_cell myFont` is it's **value**. I don't know, maybe you want `cells[j].getAttribute("class");` or simply `cells[j].className`. If you want to get the content of the element, you want `innerHTML` though.

Comment: looping is fine at the alert of cell it went for loop but value of cell show null or here is multiple class in td it content two word might be issue with this space but i can't change it

Comment: no border_cell myFont is not value it the class name for all row value is 1, or abc.

Comment: Yes, it's the value of the `class` attribute. You are using `getAttribute` so I assumed you wanted to get the value of the `class` attribute, but passed the wrong argument. What else did you try to do with  `cells[j].getAttribute("border_cell myFont")`? As I already said, if you want to get the content of the element, use `innerHTML`. The content has nothing to do with attributes.

Comment: You can't do getAttribute("border_cell myFont"), that will look for an attribute type called 'border_cell myFont'.

Comment: @Felix Kling can give me demo how to access innerHTML i am new at javascript

Comment: I prefer to use "textContent".

Answer (score 0):

Typo? "getElementsByTagname" instead of "getElementByTagName"

```
var rows=rs_body.getElementByTagName("tr");
var cells=rows[i].getElementByTagName("td");
```

Both times wrong.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: OP said "looping is fine". If that was the issue, OP would not even see an `alert`.

Comment: i want value of all td in var cell